# MapKit: How to update the polyline on the map upon the movement of one of the annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am working on an app like Uber. I succeeded in drawing the line between the user and the driver on the map but I want also to track the driver movements, how to update the polyline according to driver moves.

Note: I have an API that I can get the current location of the driver.

```
let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let destinationPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
    let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
    let destinationItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlaceMark)
    let sourceAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    sourceAnotation.title = sourceAddress
    if let location = sourcePlaceMark.location {
        sourceAnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }
    let destinationAnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    destinationAnotation.title = destinationAddress
    if let location = destinationPlaceMark.location {
        destinationAnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
    }
    mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnotation, destinationAnotation], animated: true)
    
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
    directionRequest.destination = destinationItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .automobile
    let direction = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    direction.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR FOUND : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the most important part working, getting driver's location, and  drawing a route to it.

Now, you can simply run a [timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) and periodically perform following steps:

- get driver location
- check if new location is different (beyond some threshold) from previous location
- calculate new route with updated location
- remove old route polyline overlay
- add new route polyline overlay